# Python - Pandas: Construct date with year, week of year and day of week

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way, using pandas, to construct a `Timestamp` based on 3 input:

- the year (ex: 2010)
- the week of the year (ex: 3 : the 3rd week)
- the day of the week: (for instance Monday)

In that particular example, the result would be `Timestamp('2010-01-18')`

Anyone have a hint of a clever way to achieve this?

Comment: Try df['DateTime'] = df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']].apply(lambda s : datetime.datetime(*s),axis = 1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate a date using the logic you've provided like this:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2010-3-Monday", "%Y-%W-%A")
datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 18, 0, 0)
```

You may need to adjust your format, depending on what, exactly, you are passing to `strptime`, but you can find the appropriate formatting options [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)